# What does this statement of Abu Yaal Fura Al Hanbali in Ahkam As Sultaniyyah means

Tags: fiqh, slavery

ويجوز شراء أولاد الْحَرْبِ مِنْهُمْ، كَمَا يَجُوزُ سَبْيُهُمْ.
وَيَجُوزُ شِرَاءُ أولاد العهد منهم، ولا يجوز سبيهم.

[كتاب الأحكام السلطانية لأبي يعلى الفراء](https://shamela.ws/book/22877/128) Page 145

What does the word  ("سَبْيُهُمْ") here means

Please also provide explanation for this statement in detail (Update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means capture them as spoils of war for the purpose of enslavement, being used in particular for women and children as opposed to adult males. The statement is about the legality of purchasing a Harbi or Mu‘aahid's child from him as opposed to capturing him.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation. Because does it confuses me a lot.
Does he meant it is permissible to a Harbi or Mu‘aahid's child as slaves but capturing is only permissible in case of Harbi's child